# Что здесь значит слово «перекрывать»?

Tags: значения

> Впрочем, количество компаний, принимающих биткойн, уже записывается числом почти с пятью нулями (статистика получена от сервисов, **перекрывающих** криптовалютные платежи обычными деньгами: Coinbase, BitPay и др.; они помогают принимать биткойны) и среди них есть как мелкие предприятия, так и гиганты с миллиардными оборотами вроде Dell, Overstock.

Источник: http://www.computerra.ru/108179/cheap-btc/

Comment: Значение какое-то нетипичное. Видимо имеется в виду что платежи в биткоинах этими сервисами переводятся в платежи в обычных валютах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это какой-то ad-hoc термин, образованный от довольно широко распространенного *покрывать платеж* (что есть собственно оплачивать) заменой приставки.

Значение его очевидно по контексту — если Алиса выставляет счет Бобу, но не напрямую, а опосредованно — через Виктора, который не просто проводит транзакцию, но делает что-то еще (в данном случае — конвертирует валюты) таким образом, что платеж от Боба к Алисе как таковой перестает существовать, ибо деньги, скорее всего, аккумулируются у Виктора и переводятся Алисе более крупными партиями; то вот это самое, чем занимается Виктор и названо здесь *перекрытием платежа*.

Зачем это здесь это так названо, я не знаю — я не смог нагуглить более ни одного примера употребления глагола *перекрывать* в этом значении.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an *sofisticated* definition of 'bitcoin exchange' IMO.